# Is it possible to run the workflow again if any component is unpublished(i.e. the workflow should start as soon as the component is unpublished))

Tags: workflow

Is it possible to run the workflow again if any component is unpublished in tridion(i.e. the workflow should start as soon as the component is unpublished in tridion)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just create event handler which will kick in when component is unpublished. Inside this handler simply call `Component.Save` and workflow process, which is attached to component will kick in. Alternatively, you can create a new process instance with some different process definition.